# Need to put this into a loop

Tags: powershell

I have a piece of code that works but I not very elegant, it looks at a directory full of backups, deletes all but the last modified.

```
$path = "C:\Users\test"

Get-ChildItem "$path\*.*" -include *.data* | 
   Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | 
      Select-Object -Skip 1 |Remove-Item -Force

Get-ChildItem "$path\*.*" -include *.enroll* | 
   Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | 
       Select-Object -Skip 1 |Remove-Item -Force

Get-ChildItem "$path\*.*" -include *.govern* | 
   Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | 
       Select-Object -Skip 1 |Remove-Item -Force
```

I tried this but it does'nt work,

```
$sites = @("data","govern","enroll")
$path = "C:\Users\test"

for ($i=0; $i -lt $sites.Length; $i++) {
    Get-ChildItem "$path\*.*" -include "*.$sites[$i]*" | 
        Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | 
            Select-Object -Skip 1 |Remove-Item -Force
}
```

Just a nice elegant loop is all I'm looking for.

Comment: `foreach($site in $sites){Get-ChildItem "$path\*.*" -include "*.$site*" |...` or with your for change include to `"*.$($sites[$i])*"`

Comment: Thanks LotPings, "*.$($sites[$i])*" this worked a treat, cheers